# Can't create QT postgresql plugin for Symbian device

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql, symbian

I'm trying to create postgresql plugin for Symbian device but I can't compile it. I'm working on Windows 7 64bit.

I did everything according to this article: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/sql-driver.html#qpsql

```
C:\QtSDK\QtSources\4.8.1\src\plugins\sqldrivers\psql>qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\8.3\include" "LIBS+=C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\8.3\lib\libpq.lib" psql.pro
WARNING: (internal):1: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated.
```

So, it looked OK. Then...

```
C:\...drivers\psql>C:\QtSDK\Symbian\tools\sbs\win32\mingw\bin\make debug-gcce
sbs -c arm.v5.udeb.gcce4_4_1
python.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
make: *** [debug-gcce] Error 9009
```

I noticed, that sbs_home was set to python directory but it was not in the path, then the make could not find the script raptor_start.py:

```
C:\...drivers\psql>echo %sbs_home%
C:\QtSDK\Symbian\tools\sbs\win32\python27
C:\...drivers\psql>set path=%path%;%sbs_home%
C:\...drivers\psql>C:\QtSDK\Symbian\tools\sbs\win32\mingw\bin\make debug-gcce
sbs -c arm.v5.udeb.gcce4_4_1
python.exe: can't open file C:\QtSDK\Symbian\tools\sbs\win32\python27\python\raptor_start.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
make: *** [debug-gcce] Error 2
C:\...drivers\psql>set sbs_home=C:\QtSDK\Symbian\tools\sbs
```

so, when I started compiling I got this error:

```
C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt474/epoc32/include/stdapis/stlportv5/stl/_istream.c:650: warning: suggest parentheses around '&&' within '||' target     : epoc32\release\armv5\udeb\qsqlpsql.dll    [arm.v5.udeb.gcce4_4_1]
FAILED linkandpostlink  for arm.v5.udeb.gcce4_4_1: epoc32\release\armv5\udeb\qsqlpsql.dll
  mmp: qsqlpsql_dll.mmp
c:/qtsdk/symbian/tools/gcce4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-symbianelf/4.4.1/../../../../arm-none-symbianelf/bin/ld.exe: warning: C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt474/epoc32/release/armv5/udeb/usrt3_1.lib(ucppinit.o) uses variable-size enums yet the output is to use 32-bit enums; use of enum values across objects may fail
C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt474/epoc32/build/psql/c_8d95259b570e1766/qsqlpsql_dll/armv5/udeb/qsql_psql.o: In function `qMakeError':    C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/sql/drivers/psql/qsql_psql.cpp:175: undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
```

....many undefined references...

```
C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/sql/drivers/psql/qsql_psql.cpp:117: undefined reference to `PQfreemem'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

mingw32-make[1]: *** [C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt474/epoc32/release/armv5/udeb/qsqlpsql.dll] Error 1
sbs: error: The make-engine exited with errors.

sbs : warnings: 3
sbs : errors: 2

built 'arm.v5.udeb.gcce4_4_1'

Run time 5 seconds

sbs: build log in C:\QtSDK\Symbian\SDKs\Symbian3Qt474\epoc32\build\Makefile.2012-06-26-15-03-12.78-2996.log
make: *** [debug-gcce] Error 1
```

Has anybody idea, what with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to build an Symbian/ARM application using precompiled binary postgresql client library for Windows. This won't ever work. The [instructions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qpsql) you refer to only show how to build for OS X, Unix and Mac targets natively. You're cross compiling for Symbian.

You'd first need to obtain a binary version of the postgresql client library compiled for Symbian. It might exist out there, or you may need to compile it yourself. I don't think that the library supports Symbian as a target, and I couldn't readily find any Symbian ports for download. You may be out of luck for a trivial solution. A port might not be entirely out of the question, though -- perhaps the platform-specific code is localized enough.